# What's the best way to develop exe apps?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe, desktop-application

I want to start making professional exe apps, but how can i do it?
I started with Windows Forms but heard that it's not good for aestic applications.
Then i started with UWP, but it can't be extracted to exe file :x

I looked for WPF in the internet and it says they are the same as UWP with exe files.
So how the professional apps are being made? How can i make them?

I'm using Visual Studio and I want to make the apps in C#.

Comment: WPF has nothing to do with UWP. You can use XAML to design your GUI in an UWP app, but it's still not WPF.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I said i tried with UWP but I can't use just the exe  file ( need to run it through Visual Studio). When i'm trying to 'publish' it from Visual Studio it extract like package of the file, but i still cannot run only the exe file

Comment: You need an exe app, You have 2 options WinForms and WPF. To speak simply UWP apps go into Windows App Store and can be installed from there.
Can you run UWP app on another machine: Yes. Is it going to be exe: No.

You should look into the official documents to understand what is UWP before going into it.

Right now you can create a WPF app and even then it is not going to be a single exe only, It will have a lot of DLLs and other files to be shipped along with it.

Comment: Yeah, I know it won't be only exe file I just wanted to know how to make those exe files to run on computer. Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the WPF C# packages installed just type inside the project search bar:

[image]

Click on the project, give a name, click next

[image]

And there you go, you have a WPF project.

Then follow some beginner friendly WPF tutorial

https://wpf-tutorial.com/

Comment: I tried with UWP but I couldn't extract it into Exe file ( actually there was an exe file, but couldn't be launched, and when i want to publish the project it creates only like packages of the program not exe file with maybe needed files like .dll etc. )

Will I be able to do 'normal' exe programs with WPF? I mean, im writing program, then i'll extract it into exe file and will it work normally on computer?